# asp:label make it display over multiple lines

Tags: asp.net, text

I have the code below and would like the data that is coming from the database to be viewed over multiple line and not a single line. option two does do this but the editor comes up so that they they can add font and stuff to the text is there a method to disable this

```
**Option one** 
<asp:Label ID="questionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("question") %>' />

**Option two**
<asp:TextBox ID="questionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("question") %>'  TextMode="MultiLine"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect the textbox, just pur ReadOnly="true"

```
<asp:TextBox ID="questionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("question") %>'  TextMode="MultiLine ReadOnly="true""/>
```

Comment: do you mean the border around the text box? If so, you can disable by css, or another option should be to use `<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `\n` as new line character then you can use the following

use `Text='<%# (Eval("question").ToString()).Replace("\n","<br/>") %>'`

applying to your code

```
<asp:Label ID="questionLabel" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# (Eval("question").ToString()).Replace("\n","<br/>") %>' />
```

Comment: no i dont use that, a clientd adds data into the system.